# Updating plot using Select Widget issue

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bokeh

I am currently trying to write a program that will switch between two sets of data when different options are chosen from the select widget. I am trying to make this program as autonomous as possible so in the future when people update the data they don't have to modify the code at all and the updates will happen automatically.

Currently, my issue is that when I select 'White' I want the plot to update but nothing is happening. 
The two data sets are currently a dict of lists, one labeled 'White_dict' and the other labeled 'black_dict' solely to represent the color of the material for the data (I know its kinda ironic).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd
from plot_tools import add_hover
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict


bokeh_doc = curdoc()


material_types = pd.read_csv('data/material-information.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('data/Black_Materials_total_reflecatance.csv')
black_df = pd.read_csv('data/Black_Materials_total_reflecatance.csv')
white_df = pd.read_csv('data/SPIE18_white_all.csv')

names = []
w_names = []
black_dict = defaultdict(list)
white_dict = defaultdict(list)

for name, w_name in zip(df, white_df):
    names.append(name)
    w_names.append(w_name)



data = pd.read_csv('data/Black_Materials_total_reflecatance.csv', usecols = names)
w_data = pd.read_csv('data/SPIE18_white_all.csv', usecols = w_names)

for name, w_name in zip(names, w_names):
    for i in range(0, 2250):
        black_dict[name].append(data[name][i])
        white_dict[w_name].append(w_data[w_name][i])

mySource = ColumnDataSource(data = black_dict)

#create total reflectance figure
total_fig = figure(plot_width = 650, plot_height = 350,
           title = 'Total Reflectance', 
           x_axis_label = 'Wavelength(nm)', y_axis_label = 'Total Reflectance', 
           x_range = (250, 2500), y_range = (0,10),
           title_location = 'above', sizing_mode = "scale_both",
           toolbar_location = "below",
           tools = "box_zoom, pan, wheel_zoom, save")

select = Select(title="Material Type", options=['Black', 'White'])

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if new == 'White':
        mySource.data = white_dict
    else:
        mySource.data = black_dict

for name, color in zip(mySource.data, Turbo256):
    if name != 'nm':
        total_fig.line('nm', name, line_width = .7, source = mySource, color = color) 

select.on_change('value', update_plot)

bokeh_doc.add_root(total_fig)
bokeh_doc.add_root(select)
```

I'm currently using bokeh serve bokehWork.py to launch the server. If anyone has any idea on what I should fix it would be much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
Adding data for Black_materials_total_reflectance.csv 
[Black Reflectance Data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNxVLlXnNutgk7Mvo2EtyMSsD7_mQgK-sl6zqOTOlgk/edit?usp=sharing)

Adding data for White_all.csv
[White Reflectance Data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13fjQUTU4lRZ9SRq4syamsz2wwhsPWzlN4ZSw0tmBL0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. But I can't really test it because there's no test data. Can you provide some?

Comment: Yea of course! The first column is 'nm' and underneath is ranged from 250 to 2500. The rest of the columns are test sample names such as 'P09' and there is value for each nm that will range from 0 to 100. Both plots should have similar data just with different samples.

Comment: When you ask a question, StackOverflow asks to provide a minimal _reproducible_ example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your description of data may be enough, but it would be much better if the data was just there in the code block as a plain Python data structure or at least something that I can copy directly, without inventing myself.

Comment: So sorry about that. I went ahead and added example data to some google docs and linked it in the post for each separate samples file. I didn't post it originally because it is a fairly large set of data and doesn't fit on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. You read the same files multiple times and you do a lot of work that Pandas and Bokeh can already do for you
2. (the main one) You do not take into account the fact that different CSV files have different column names

Here's a fixed version. Notice also the usage of the palette. With just `Turbo256` you were getting almost the same color for all lines.

```py
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.palettes import turbo
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

black_ds = ColumnDataSource(pd.read_csv('/home/p-himik/Downloads/Black_material_data - Sheet1.csv').set_index('nm'))
white_ds = ColumnDataSource(pd.read_csv('/home/p-himik/Downloads/White Materials Sample - Sheet1.csv').set_index('nm'))

total_fig = figure(plot_width=650, plot_height=350,
                   title='Total Reflectance',
                   x_axis_label='Wavelength(nm)', y_axis_label='Total Reflectance',
                   title_location='above', sizing_mode="scale_both",
                   toolbar_location="below",
                   tools="box_zoom, pan, wheel_zoom, save")

total_fig.x_range.range_padding = 0
total_fig.x_range.only_visible = True
total_fig.y_range.only_visible = True

palette = turbo(len(black_ds.data) + len(white_ds.data))


def plot_lines(ds, color_offset, visible):
    renderers = []
    for name, color in zip(ds.data, palette[color_offset:]):
        if name != 'nm':
            r = total_fig.line('nm', name, line_width=.7, color=color,
                               source=ds, visible=visible)
            renderers.append(r)
    return renderers


black_renderers = plot_lines(black_ds, 0, True)
white_renderers = plot_lines(white_ds, len(black_ds.data), False)

select = Select(title="Material Type", options=['Black', 'White'], value='Black')


def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    wv = new == 'White'
    for r in white_renderers:
        r.visible = wv
    for r in black_renderers:
        r.visible = not wv


select.on_change('value', update_plot)

bokeh_doc = curdoc()
bokeh_doc.add_root(total_fig)
bokeh_doc.add_root(select)
```